# meteorjs iron-router event for route exited

Tags: events, meteor, exit, iron-router

Does iron-router have any events I can tie into for when the user exits a route?  In my example, I have a setTimeout() call that I start when the route is first loaded.  But when they leave that route (by whatever means), I want to clearTimeout() so it doesn't keep firing after they've left that route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, I guess it helps if I RTFM.  All I had to do was define 'onStop' in my RouteController.  duh, of course it's that simple.